# creating runnable jar file programmatically, main class manifest issue

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to create a runnable jar file however I believe I am having problems with the manifest. I have been informed by another post on this site that setting the "Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS" attribute of your manifest file to the value of your runnable class will create a runnable jar file upon which on start, the file will run the class value that you entered as your runnable file. Unfortunately I am having trouble with the syntax a little bit. Here is what I am trying at the moment:

```
String f = "LicenseFiller";
        String version = "1.0.0";
        String author = "concretepage";
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        Attributes global = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        global.put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, version);
        global.put(new Attributes.Name("Created-By"), author);
        global.put(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS, f);
```

There are no error messages however, when executed the program will produce a jar file but not a runnable jar file. When I create runnable jar file in eclipse and then run jar file, it works perfectly so there is nothing in the LicenseFiller.class that is causing the issue. Could someone please correct my syntax? Thankyou.

**UPDATE:**

When I decompiled and inspected my own compiled jar to the one eclipse makes. The manifest files both contain the same value for the main class however the eclipse made jar has many more files in the runnable jar file but I believe these are just excess classes because they are made from the same default package.

**Manifest of my jar:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: concretepage
Main-Class: LicenseFiller
```

**Manifest of eclipse:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: LicenseFiller

Name: org/jdom2/filter/
Specification-Title: JDOM Filter Classes
Implementation-Title: org.jdom2.filter
Implementation-Version: 2.0.5
Specification-Version: 2.0.0
Specification-Vendor: jdom.org
Implementation-Vendor: jdom.org

Name: org/jdom2/adapters/
Specification-Title: JDOM Adapter Classes
Implementation-Title: org.jdom2.adapters
Implementation-Version: 2.0.5
Specification-Version: 2.0.0
Specification-Vendor: jdom.org
Implementation-Vendor: jdom.org

Name: org/jdom2/
Specification-Title: JDOM Classes
Implementation-Title: org.jdom2
Implementation-Version: 2.0.5
Specification-Version: 2.0.0
Specification-Vendor: jdom.org
Implementation-Vendor: jdom.org

Name: org/jdom2/input/
Specification-Title: JDOM Input Classes
Implementation-Title: org.jdom2.input
Implementation-Version: 2.0.5
Specification-Version: 2.0.0
Specification-Vendor: jdom.org2
Implementation-Vendor: jdom.org

Name: org/jdom2/output/
Specification-Title: JDOM Output Classes
Implementation-Title: org.jdom2.output
Implementation-Version: 2.0.5
Specification-Version: 2.0.0
Specification-Vendor: jdom.org
Implementation-Vendor: jdom.org

Name: org/jdom2/transform/
Specification-Title: JDOM Transformation Classes
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is, and possible error messages? Also, a link to the other post you mentioned might make it clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The name of a class looks like `java.lang.Integer` or `com.mycompany.myproject.LicenseFiller`, not like `bin//LicenseFiller.class`

Comment: Okay, so my class file is located in the default package in the bin folder. How would this be displayed in terms of "com.mycompany.myproject.LicenseFiller"

Comment: If it's in the default package (which is an extremely bad idea), its name is LicenseFiller. And the LicenseFiller.class file should thus be at the root of the jar file, not under a bin directory. The directory tree must match with the package tree.

Comment: Okay, Just as a note I do usually use packages but for practising and testing etc. I just use the default package. Anyway I've edited my code but its still not compiling as a runnable JAR file

Comment: Without seeing your code, and without seeing what your jar file contains, it's quite hard to help. At least provide the output of jar tvf theProducedJarFile.jar, and show us the contents of it manifest file.